# libCurl : curl_easy_setopt in one method and curl_easy_perform in another does not work

Tags: libcurl

I have a code,  where,  in one local function I use `curl_easy_setopt` to set the proxy URL. And in another local function I call `curl_easy_perform`. But when te control moves from one function to another, the proxy url set using local variable contains junk characters and the DNS query returns an error. The libcurl help page says that when we do setopt the string values is copied by the curl library. But I feel the library just referes to that value whenever it needs it. It doesn't copy the string. So if local variable is used to set proxy url, it will contain junk by the time I call `curl_easy_perform`.

Following is the example code snippet.

```
void funcSetOpt
{
    char ProxyUrl[] = "someproxy";
    curl_easy_setopt(curlHandle, CURLOPT_PROXY, ProxyUrl);
}

void funcPerform
{
    curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That would imply that you're using a fairly old libcurl version and the following section from the [curl_easy_setopt](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) man page might affect you:

> Before version 7.17.0, strings were not copied. Instead the user was
>   forced keep them available until libcurl no longer needed them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Checked my libcurl version and it is 7.15.1

Comment: Then my answer was spot on!